# Qual a diferença entre authorizecore e onauthorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Quando vamos criar um atributo do tipo `AuthorizeAttribute`
Temos essas 2 propriedades a serem sobreescritas

Qual a diferença entre as duas? Ambas parecem ter a mesma função

[Edit]

O namespace do atributo citado é System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sucintamente:

- Caso apenas queiras redefinir o algoritmo para determinar se uma request é autorizada ou não, faz override ao `AuthorizeCore`.
- Caso contrário, usa o `OnAuthorization`.

Basicamente, o `OnAuthorization` verifica se a/o action/controller tem o atributo `AllowAnonymousAttribute`. Se tiver o atributo, a autenticacao nao é necessária. Se não tiver o atributo, então chama o `AuthorizeCore` para determinar se a request é autorizada.

Após correr o `AuthorizeCore`, o `OnAuthorization` define como responder a requests não autorizadas.

PS: O código fonte dos dois métodos pode ser encontrado no [GitHub](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/4e40cdef9c8a8226685f95ef03b746bc8322aa92/src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs#L78).

Comment: sim é do asp.net mvc e não do webapi, irei atualizar a pergunta

Comment: Porquê o voto negativo?

Comment: oi? não fiz voto negativo nenhum, já que a sua resposta está correta

Comment: @Rod A pergunta nao era para si, era para quem deu o voto :P

Answer (score 2):

## [`AuthorizeCore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.authorizecore%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

É o método que efetivamente toma a decisão se o usuário está autorizado ou não a acessar um determinado contexto. Aqui que se confere as *roles*, as regras normais, as regras especiais, e assim por diante. O retorno é apenas um booleano.

## [`OnAuthorization`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.onauthorization(v=vs.118).aspx)

É um método que realiza ações adicionais que têm a ver com a verificação da autorização em si, mas não é exatamente a verificação da autorização. Por exemplo, colocar condições para verificar se a checagem da autorização em si deve ser feita ou não.

Diferentemente do `AuthorizeCore`, não devolve resultado (`void`). A diferença entre ambos está basicamente no escopo de utilidade de cada.

Comment: E há como capturar o controller através do HttpContextBase do authorizeCore ?

Comment: @Rod Aqui explica como obter o controller, ou o nome do controller: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9022179/857807

Comment: @dcastro muita gambi pra pegar o controller nesse link aí, irei usar OnAuthorization mesmo, valeu :D